# Turn off the "follow mouse" feature when I press transformation shortcuts?

Tags: transforms, shortcut, 3d-manipulator

I'm more experienced with Maya and trying to transition to Blender. Blender's default settings for the move, rotate and scale hotkeys (G, R, S) are weird to me; when I press them, the selected object follows my cursor; I want to change the hotkey settings so that when I press those hotkeys, it just turns on the manipulators rather than following my cursor, just like in Maya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want shortcuts that are closer to Maya and other software packages, I suggest to use the *Industry Compatible* keymap. Open the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*), then switch to it under *Keymap*. In this keymap, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd> will function [the way they do in Maya](https://www.autodesk.com/shortcuts/maya). There is more to this keymap, so try it out.

[image: Keymap]